# extract a word after a word from a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a big note column in which there is a word NUMBER_OF_SERVERS_03 the 03 can be any 2 digits or it can have n digits and there is digits after that for example NUMBER_OF_SERVERS_03 2 i want to extract the digits after that for eg

```
Notes Column - 'asdasd asdasda asdasd NUMBER_OF_SERVERS_03 24 hkashii rwnijt'
output will should be 24
```

Thanks
Rakesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with **match parameters** as follows:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2      REGEXP_SUBSTR('asdasd asdasda asdasd NUMBER_OF_SERVERS_03 24 hkashii rwnijt',
  3      'NUMBER_OF_SERVERS_[0-9]+\s+([0-9]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) as RESULT
  4  FROM
  5      DUAL;

RE
--
24

-- Example with spaces and different server number
SQL> SELECT
  2      REGEXP_SUBSTR('asdasd asdasda asdasd NUMBER_OF_SERVERS_11   10 hkashii rwnijt',
  3      'NUMBER_OF_SERVERS_[0-9]+\s+([0-9]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) as RESULT
  4  FROM
  5      DUAL;

RE
--
10

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(notes, '^.*NUMBER_OF_SERVERS_[0-9]+[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*$', '\1')
from (select 'asdasd asdasda asdasd NUMBER_OF_SERVERS_03 24 hkashii rwnijt' as notes from dual)
```

If you know that the number follows that string with a space, then you can slightly simplify this to:

```
select regexp_replace(notes, '^.*NUMBER_OF_SERVERS_[0-9]+ ([0-9]+).*$', '\1')
```

Comment: will this replace the notes column in the database?

Comment: @Rakesh119 . . . You would have to use an `update` for that, but the expression would be the same.

Comment: I want to get the output as 24 and there can more than one space between NUMBER_OF SERVERS_03 and 24, but presently it is pulling the entire string

Comment: @Rakesh119 . . . Did you run this code?  It does what you want:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9e1e04ce60a6b8f82ba002d34dc72656.  And it handles an arbitrary number of spaces before the number as well.